# ORA-32000: write to SPFILE requested but SPFILE is not modifiable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm not able to alter the SORT_AREA_SIZE in my database.

[image]

Comment: Please post the o/p of the below query: show parameter pfile;

Comment: What happens when you run `SHOW SPPARAMETERS`? Is your instance running with a spfile: Run `show parameter spfile` and see if you get a return value.

Comment: I get back `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database\SPFILEXE.ORA`

Answer (score -1):

Use the command:

```
create pfile ='loc' from spfile;
```

To create a `pfile` named `loc`. The edit this file and change the parameter in this `pfile`. Now create a new `spfile` from it:

```
create spfile from pfile ='loc';
```

Answer (score -2):

Delete the SPFILE in

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database\SPFILEXE.ORA
```

Or where you have it stored

Comment: Terrible idea. How would the OP start the database without it?

Comment: `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\database\SPFILEXE.ORA`